# unmatched curly bracket console error

Tags: javascript

i am getting an error because of an unmatched curly bracket and i have no idea why, all brackets are closed properly, still my console is still complaining.

```
    var facebookProfile = {
      name: "Mina",
      friends:2,
      messages:["i like apples","i hate carrtos"],
      postMessage: postMessage(message){
        facebookProfile.messages.push(message);
      },
      deleteMessage: deleteMessage(index){
        facebookProfile.messages.splice(index,1);
      },
      addFriend: addFriend(){
        facebookProfile.friends +=1;
      },
      removeFriend: removeFriend(){
        facebookProfile.friends -=1;
      }
    };
```

i am going crazy, i would appreciate any help :)

Comment: `Mina` should be `"Mina"`

Comment: `postMessage: postMessage(message){}` is not valid JavaScript. Either do `postMessage(message){}` or `postMessage: function postMessage(message){}`.

Comment: You need to change `postMessage: postMessage(message) {` to  `postMessage: function(message) {` for all your functions

Comment: `addFriend: function () {...}` and the same for the next function.

Comment: thanks @Pointy, but still does not solve the issue.

Comment: `postMessage: (message) => {` is also valid syntax

Comment: @SterlingArcher If you're running under something that supports ES6.

Comment: @DaveNewton you mean like every modern browser? If you fall in the X% not running modern, transpile.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Sure. But when someone is clearly not overly-JS-aware specificity is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 var facebookProfile = {
   name: 'Mina',
   friends: 2,
   messages: ["i like apples", "i hate carrtos"],
   postMessage: function(message) {
     facebookProfile.messages.push(message);
   },
   deleteMessage: function(index) {
     facebookProfile.messages.splice(index, 1);
   },
   addFriend: function() {
     facebookProfile.friends += 1;
   },
   removeFriend: function() {
     facebookProfile.friends -= 1;
   }
 };
```

You called Mina like a variable and not a string.
You called all your functions incorrectly.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v40gLu0v/)

Answer (score -1):

You omitted to declare **postMessage**, **deleteMessage**, **addFriend**, **removeFriend** in your **facebookProfile** object as functions.
Check the code below:

```js
    var facebookProfile = {
      name: "Mina",
      friends:2,
      messages:["i like apples","i hate carrtos"],
        postMessage: function postMessage(message){
        facebookProfile.messages.push(message);
      },
      deleteMessage: function deleteMessage(index){
        facebookProfile.messages.splice(index,1);
      },
      addFriend: function addFriend(){
        facebookProfile.friends +=1;
      },
      removeFriend: function removeFriend(){
        facebookProfile.friends -=1;
      }
    };
```